# How do I interpret direct traffic that lands on random pages?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, landing-page

Looking at yesterday, according to Google Analytics, I got six direct visitors to my site (their source/medium is `direct/(none)`). Only one ended up at the actual domain. The other five ended up at miscellaneous foo.com/xyz.html. I did not send out links to people by email, and I'm not sure how likely it is the people would have copy/pasted the URLs.

How do the visitors end up there? Is there a way to better capture where they might be coming from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It basically means these requests are missing the http referrer header. There are several reasons why that would be the case -

1. A https page has a link to your website, and the user follows that link. Browsers don't send the referrer in case of a https -> http transition. A simple case is a search engine accessed via https.
2. They are behind some kind of proxy that strips out referrer headers, or they have deliberately installed a browser plugin to do that.
3. Someone is trying to scrape your website using a custom program (not browser), and is not sending the http referrer.

6 requests is a very small number. If you see several hundreds of requests, you could try to co-relate and find out more information. Otherwise, there is no definite answer.

Comment: Okay, I think the HTTPS sounds the likeliest (most of the traffic is pretty local to people I know). Is it possible that I would get both traffic attributed to Facebook, and not, based on the type of login (HTTP/HTTPS) that users are using? (The 6 is over 2 days, or 15 of 26 visitors week, 1 of whom went to the root.)

Comment: @mfg - I didn't understand your question. What do you mean by attributed to "facebook and not"?

Comment: @Sripathi - mfg wants to know whether Facebook may be sending traffic to the site from both HTTP and HTTPS sources (Facebook-specific question). Just tested and it does appear Facebook links out from both HTTP and HTTPS contexts.

Comment: @danlefree - Oh ok. I might add, Facebook and Google both have http and https versions, but not many people use it.

Comment: @dan and sri, Sorry if this is too far from the original question, but is there a manner of linking (ie. the type of URL I use in my post) I can use to attempt to maintain the header (I'm *imagining* some `rel=` attribute to the effect of the capturing it), or does HTTPS always strip it out?

Comment: The only way you can influence the browser is by making your website https enabled. A https -> https transition preserves the referrer header.

Comment: +1. This is an excellent answer. Worth including: Non-web sources, like mobile or desktop apps.